# GLSL 120 vertex shader showing less active uniforms than shader program

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl, uniform

I'm using opengl version 2.1, glsl 120, lwjgl 3.
Whenever I call GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(), it doesn't get recognized by the shader program. After debugging all shaders and programs return no errors.

A cube is drawn to the window(since no projection it appears as a quad).
Shader program that compiles with no errors and works:

```
#version 120
attribute vec3 position;
uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform mat4 proj;
void main()
{
    gl_Position =  vec4(position, 1.0); // See how we directly give a vec3 to vec4's constructor
}
```

Nothing is drawn to window.
Shader program compiles with no errors but nothing shows on the screen:

```
#version 120
attribute vec3 position;
uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform mat4 proj;
void main()
{
    gl_Position =  proj * vec4(position, 1.0); // See how we directly give a vec3 to vec4's constructor
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 120
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Programs always link and compile but the uniform proj doesnt work.

This is the code where uniform data is sent:

```
    GL20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram); 
    int model = GL20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "modelView");//used get attrib here instead of GL20.glGetUniformLocation();
    Matrix4f modelView = new Matrix4f().translate(.5f, .5f, .5f);
    GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(model, false, modelView.get(buffer));

    int proj = GL20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "proj");//and here
    Matrix4f projection = new Matrix4f().
                          perspective((float)Math.toRadians(45), 1.0f, 0.1f, 100f).
                          lookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f, //eye 
                                 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, //center
                                 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f);//up
    GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(proj, false, projection.get(buffer));

    //draw container
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

{updated} put gluseprogram before call to gluniformmatrix4fv
Still nothing is drawn to screen. When Identity matrix is sent to proj then multiplied by vec4 the cube disappears.

Checking:

```
GL20.glGetShaderiv(vertexID, GL20.GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, success);
```

in vertex shader returns zero
while checking:

```
GL20.glGetProgramiv(shaderID, GL20.GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, success);
```

in shader program returns 1 or 2 when proj and modelView are being used in main method.

[solved update]
was using get attrib location instead of get uniform location.

Comment: What does `projection.get` do? The [lwjgl Matrix4f](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Matrix4f.html) class doesn't provide this function

Comment: LWJGL version 3 got rid of all of the matrix math. I'm using JOML, Java opengl math library. whenever you call the get method on the matrix it will return whatever was in that matrix and put it into a buffer, which is the data structure that opengl wants for most of its functions.

Comment: Is `buffer` a 16-float buffer? You should really create a MVCE, otherwise we can just guess where the problem is.

Comment: buffer is a 16 float buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Uniforms are *per program state* in OpenGL. All the `glUniform*()` functions set the uniforms of the **currently active program object**. You have to call `glUseProgram` before you can set the uniforms of that very program.

Comment: I tried putting glUseProgram before and after, but that still doesn't change the outcome. Whenever I add a uniform mat4 and multiply it in the main method, the program doesn't draw anything to the screen. Everything still compiles and links without any error. When checking how many gl uniforms there are glgetshaderiv and glgetprogramiv return 1 or 2 when mat4 are in the main method. Nothing gets drawn correctly.

Comment: What makes you think that setting the uniform is the issue?

Comment: Whether they are set doesn't change the execution, but when multiplying the matrix by the vector what was on the screen previously is gone. I think the issue is that the shader isn't receiving the uniforms correctly. Since everything compiles I assume the mat4 is empty when multiplied by the vector.

Comment: There are many possible reasons why that could happen. Setting the uniform itself is only possible while the program is active, there defintively was that error in your original program. There might be others as well.

Comment: When sending the identity matrix through glUniformMatrix to proj then multiplying by the vec4, nothing appears on the screen. This is with gluseprogram being in the correct place.

Comment: You should add more of the relevant code, to make this an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently, it is hard to tell where exactly the error may lie.